# How to find the coordinates of the user's touch?

Tags: android, arraylist, touch, touch-event, motionevent

I want to get the coordinates of the trajectory/path of the user's touch. I am storing them into an `ArrayList` and storing them on database. I used the `getX()` and `getY()` methods to get the relevant coordinates but I get only **one** set of values. Here's the code for my implementation of the same :

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


        TouchData touchData = new TouchData();
        int index = event.getActionIndex();
        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);
        ArrayList<Integer> trajX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> trajY = new ArrayList<Integer>();


        int X = (int) event.getX();
        int Y = (int) event.getY();
        trajX.add(X);
        trajY.add(Y);
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                X = (int) event.getX();
                Y = (int) event.getY();
                trajX.add(X);
                trajY.add(Y);
                if(mVelocityTracker == null) {
                    // Retrieve a new VelocityTracker object to watch the velocity of a motion.
                    mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                }
                else {
                    // Reset the velocity tracker back to its initial state.
                    mVelocityTracker.clear();
                }
                // Add a user's movement to the tracker.
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


                float centreX = button.getX() + button.getWidth()  / 2;
                float centreY = button.getY() + button.getHeight() / 2;

            

                X = (int) event.getX();
                Y = (int) event.getY();
                trajX.add(X);
                trajY.add(Y);

                long eventDuration = event.getEventTime() - event.getDownTime();

                DatabaseReference newRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://pragya-datacollector.firebaseio.com").getReference();
                touchData.setUniqueID(currentUserID);
                touchData.setTaskName(TASK_NAME);
                touchData.setTouchDuration(eventDuration);
                touchData.setTrajectoryX(trajX);
                touchData.setTrajectoryY(trajY);
                touchData.setVelocityX(velocityX);
                touchData.setVelocityY(velocityY);
                touchData.setTargetX(centreX);
                touchData.setTargetY(centreY);
                newRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        databaseReference.push().setValue(touchData);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1);
                velocityX = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity();
                velocityY = mVelocityTracker.getYVelocity();
                X = (int) event.getX();
                Y = (int) event.getY();
                trajX.add(X);
                trajY.add(Y);

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                break;
        }
        

return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

And here's the `TouchData` class:

```
public class TouchData {
    private String taskName;

    private long touchDuration;

    private List<Integer> trajectoryX;

    private List<Integer> trajectoryY;

    private float velocityX;

    private float velocityY;

    private String uniqueID;

    private float targetX;

    private float targetY;


    public TouchData() {

    }


    public String getTaskName() {
        return taskName;
    }

    public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
    }

    public List<Integer> getTrajectoryX() {
        return trajectoryX;
    }

    public void setTrajectoryX(List<Integer> trajectoryX) {
        this.trajectoryX = trajectoryX;
    }

    public List<Integer> getTrajectoryY() {
        return trajectoryY;
    }

    public void setTrajectoryY(List<Integer> trajectoryY) {
        this.trajectoryY = trajectoryY;
    }

    public long getTouchDuration() {
        return touchDuration;
    }

    public void setTouchDuration(long touchDuration) {
        this.touchDuration = touchDuration;
    }

    public float getVelocityX() {
        return velocityX;
    }

    public void setVelocityX(float velocityX) {
        this.velocityX = velocityX;
    }

    public float getVelocityY() {
        return velocityY;
    }

    public void setVelocityY(float velocityY) {
        this.velocityY = velocityY;
    }

    public String getUniqueID()
    {
        return uniqueID;
    }

    public void setUniqueID(String uniqueID) {
        this.uniqueID = uniqueID;
    }

    public float getTargetX() {
        return targetX;
    }

    public void setTargetX(float targetX) {
        this.targetX = targetX;
    }

    public float getTargetY() {
        return targetY;
    }

    public void setTargetY(float targetY) {
        this.targetY = targetY;
    }
}
```

I went through almost all the relevant questions/answers and most of them use the same functions, but for me it's giving only a single value. Is this the correct approach to do so? What's exactly wrong with this implementation?

Comment: The `dispatchTouchEvent()` method will be called once for every individual event, basically. That is, for example, it runs (and completes) once for the initial `ACTION_DOWN`, then it will run again for the following `ACTION_MOVE`, then again for the next `ACTION_MOVE`, and so on until `ACTION_UP`. You're creating new `ArrayList`s each time, so when `ACTION_UP` happens, you only have that event added. You need to move the `ArrayList` declarations/initializations out of `dispatchTouchEvent()`, and (possibly) only want to clear them on `ACTION_DOWN`, depending on what you're tracking exactly.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I mean to track the path of the user's touch for every touch session(everytime the user touches the screen). I could've initialized it in the `ACTION_MOVE` part but the problem with that it is that I store the session only on `ACTION_UP`  (when the touch session is over).  So where should I initialize it then?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it seems like you want to move both `ArrayList` lines out to the class level – e.g., `private final ArrayList<Integer> trajX = new ArrayList<>();` – and then `clear()` them in `ACTION_DOWN`, before you start adding events.

Comment: Wait, I missed something. You also need to move `TouchData touchData = new TouchData();` into `ACTION_UP`. That's the only place it's used; no need to instantiate it any earlier.

Comment: Hmm, also, I'm not entirely certain how this will behave with that Firebase operation. You might need to create copies of those `ArrayList`s when setting them to the `TouchData` object.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, it's working fine now. Thanks a ton!